# Is it possible to debug a UIWebView in Macgap?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, native

I know with regular iOS development you can set the target as a simulator, pop open Safari, and debug the webview using the developer tools. I can't seem to figure out how to do that with a macgap app though. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to activate developer tools:

In Terminal:

`defaults write com.MacGap developer 1` (MacGap1)

`defaults write com.MG developer 1` (MacGap2)

Read more about it here:

https://github.com/maccman/macgap/wiki/Switching-on-Developer-Tools

Comment: It does not seem to be working for me. Which version of MacGap should I use? Also, the Wiki page you're referencing is empty.

Comment: This works for macgap1 (right click into the window and click inspect element). If you use macgap2 (alpha) you go with: "defaults write com.MG developer 1"

Comment: I don't have anything when I rick click. Any ideas? The right click only works when I do it over a link but not all text...